# Are there any tutorials out there for creating an online quiz using jQuery PHP mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm looking for a tutorial that outlines creating an online quiz using jQuery, PHP and MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm a step by step tutorial maybe not.. but if you have an idea what you want to create you can easy search some examples. A standard quiz isn't that hard... did you program before in php?